# Running Mozilla Firefox specific code in phoneGap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, mozilla

I am creating an application for android and iOS using phoeGap. I am using Mozilla specific js library; meaning a javascript with `yield` and `let`.

Does PhoneGap have dependencies on ECMA 6 or Javascript 1.8 ? 
Is it possible to run a firefox specific code (for example: a javascript with `yield` and `let`) in phoneGap ?

Doing a test run doesn't yield any output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to run a firefox specific code (for example: a javascript with yield and let) in phoneGap ?

PhoneGap uses an OS-specific Web rendering engine. In the case of Android, it is `WebView`, which is backed by WebKit, not Gecko. In the case of Firefox OS, it will use Gecko (or some equivalent as exposed via FFOS).

Hence, you cannot assume that Firefox-specific code will work in all PhoneGap deployments, any more than you can assume that Firefox-specific code will run in all browsers.